# the value of $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^2\left(\int_0^1\left(1+x^n\right)^\frac{1}{n} \, dx-1\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

This is exercise from my lecturer, for IMC preparation. I haven't found any idea.

Find the value of

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^2\left(\int_0^1 \left(1+x^n\right)^\frac{1}{n} \, dx-1\right)$$

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} (1 + x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \, dx
&= \left[ -(1-x)(1+x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \right]_{0}^{1} + \int_{0}^{1} (1-x)(1 + x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}-1}x^{n-1} \, dx \\
&= 1 + \int_{0}^{1} (1-x) (1 + x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}-1} x^{n-1} \, dx
\end{align*}

so that we have

\begin{align*}
n^{2} \left( \int_{0}^{1} (1 + x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \, dx - 1 \right)
&= \int_{0}^{1} n^{2} (1-x) (1 + x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}-1} x^{n-1} \, dx.
\end{align*}

Let $a_{n}$ denote this quantity. By the substitution $y = x^{n}$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
a_{n}
&= \int_{0}^{1} n \left(1-y^{1/n}\right) (1 + y)^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \, dy
= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} t^{\frac{1}{n}-1} (1 + y)^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \, dtdy
\end{align*}

Since $0 \leq t (1 + y) \leq 2$ and $ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} t^{-1}(1+y)^{-1} \, dtdy < \infty$, an obvious application of the dominated convergence theorem shows that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}
 = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} \frac{dtdy}{t(1+y)}
&= - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log y}{1+y} \, dy \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{m} \int_{0}^{1} y^{m-1} \log y \, dy
 = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m^2}
 = \frac{\pi^2}{12}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice work! Now it's proven :)

Comment: Very nice! The value of $\pi^2/12 = .822...$ falls within my bounds of .75 to .875 which is comforting.

Comment: @sos440 here is a shortcut I noticed. By DCT $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1} n \left(1-y^{1/n}\right) (1 + y)^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \, dy=\int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(1-y^{1/n}\right)}{1/n} (1 + y)^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \, dy=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log y}{1+y}\ dy=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$

Comment: @Chris'swisesister, that's my first approach but I was unsure if we can find a dominating function for $(1 - y^{1/n})/(1/n)$. This is why I introduced double integral.

Answer (score 5):

I get an answer that differs from 
that of user17762.
This is because the error term
is not one term of order
$\frac{x^{2n}}{n^2}$
but a number of such terms.

I get that the limit
is between
3/4 and 7/8,
but only have an infinite series
for the value.

My complete analysis follows.

$(1+x^n)^{1/n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/n}{k}x^{kn}
$.

We first look at
$\binom{1/n}{k}$.

$\begin{align}
\binom{1/n}{k}
&=\frac1{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(\frac{1}{n}-i)\\
&=\frac1{k!n^k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(1-in)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!n^k}(-1)\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(in-1)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!n^k}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(in-1)\\
\end{align}
$

so

$\begin{align}
\big|\binom{1/n}{k}\big|
=\frac1{k!n^k}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(in-1)
<\frac{1}{k!n^k}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(in)
=\frac{n^{k-1}(k-1)!}{k!n^k}
=\frac1{kn}
\end{align}
$

and

$\begin{align}
\frac{\binom{1/n}{k+1}}{\binom{1/n}{k}}
&=\frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{(k+1)!n^{k+1}}\frac{k!n^k}{(-1)^{k+1}}\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{k}(in-1)}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(in-1)}\\
&=\frac{-1}{(k+1)n}(kn+1)\\
&=-\frac{kn+1}{kn+n}\\
\end{align}
$

We now look at
$\int_0^v (1+x^n)^{1/n}\, dx$
to see what happens as $v \to 1$.

$\begin{align}
\int_0^v (1+x^n)^{1/n}\, dx
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/n}{k} \int_0^v x^{kn}\, dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/n}{k} \frac{v^{kn+1}}{kn+1}\\
&=v+\frac{v^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \binom{1/n}{k} \frac{v^{kn+1}}{kn+1}\\
&=v+\frac{v^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}+v^{2n+1}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \binom{1/n}{k} \frac{v^{(k-2)n}}{kn+1}\\
\end{align}
$

This means that the terms in
$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \binom{1/n}{k} \frac{v^{(k-2)n}}{kn+1}
$
decrease in absolute value
and, since they alternate in sign,
the series converges.
and converges even at $v=1$
because of the $\frac1{kn+1}$.

Let
$f(v, n) =
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \binom{1/n}{k} \frac{v^{(k-2)n}}{kn+1}
$.

Since
$\big|\binom{1/n}{k} \frac{1}{kn+1}\big|
< \frac1{kn(kn+1)}
$,
$|f(v, n)|
<\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac1{kn(kn+1)}
<\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac1{k^2}
<\frac1{n^2}
$.

The first term of $f(v, n)$
is
$\binom{1/n}{2}\frac{1}{2n+1}
=\frac{(1/n)(1/n-1)}{2}\frac{1}{2n+1}
=-\frac{n-1}{2n^2(2n+1)}
$
and this is between
$-\frac1{8n^2}$ and $-\frac1{4n^2}$
for $n > 3$.

Therefore the first two terms
of the expansion of
$\int_0^v (1+x^n)^{1/n}\, dx$
are both of order $1/n^2$,
so we have to consider the whole sum,
not just the first term
(after $1$).

Since
$\int_0^v (1+x^n)^{1/n}\, dx
=v+\frac{v^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}+v^{2n+1}f(v, n)
$
and all the terms exist as $v \to 1$,
$\int_0^1 (1+x^n)^{1/n}\, dx
-1-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=f(1, n)
$.

Since $f(1,n)$ 
is between
$-\frac1{8n^2}$ and $-\frac1{4n^2}$,
$-\frac1{4n^2}
<\int_0^1 (1+x^n)^{1/n}\, dx
-1-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}
<-\frac1{8n^2}
$,
$-\frac1{4}
<n^2\big(\int_0^1 (1+x^n)^{1/n}\, dx
-1\big)-\frac{n}{n+1}
<-\frac1{8}
$
so 
$1-\frac1{4}
<\lim_{n \to \infty}
n^2 \big(\int_0^1 (1+x^n)^{1/n}\, dx -1\big)
< 1-\frac1{8}
$.

Comment: +1. Actually, I have found that the exact value is equal to $\pi^2/12$.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica evaluates the integral to
$$\int_0^{1}(1+x^n)^{1/n}dx={}_2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac1n,1+\frac1n;-1\right).\tag{1}$$
Next, let us write the standard series representation for the hypergeometric function
$$_2F_1(a,b,c;t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha_kt^k,\qquad \alpha_k=\frac{\Gamma(a+k)\Gamma(b+k)\Gamma(c)}{k!\,\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c+k)}.$$
Now an easily verified claim: as $n\rightarrow\infty$, for the parameters as in (1), we have $\alpha_0=1$ and
$$\alpha_k\sim-\frac{1}{k^2n^2}+O(n^{-3}).$$
Hence we obtain
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^2\left(\int_0^{1}(1+x^n)^{1/n}dx-1\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12},
\end{align}
which is also confirmed by numerical calculation with $n\sim 10^4-10^8$.